# Can Terraform add individual Digital Ocean firewall rules?

Tags: terraform, digital-ocean

I'm building a mix of EC2 instance and DO droplets which must be able to communicate in a fully meshed manner, which requires firewall configurations for AWS and DO to have knowledge of the WAN and LAN addresses for all created resources. The number of resources per platform is variable.

When using Terraform with the AWS provider, I can create a security group and later add individual rules to it:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "sg-1" {
 
  ingress {
     ...
  }
  egress {
    ...
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "sg1-rule-1" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.sg-1.id
  ...
}
```

The DigitalOcean provider provides the `digitalocean_firewall` resource, but nothing similar to the `aws_security_group_rule` resource, which means the entire firewall ruleset must be known in advance and applied within the `digitalocean_firewall` resource block.

My only solution so far is to dynamically create the digitalocean_firewall.tf file from a template once the resources have been created, but this then requires a *second* `terraform apply` to apply the dynamic rules.

In the absence of a `digitalocean_firewall_rule` resource, is there a better approach?

Comment: If droplets are managed by Terraform, you can refer to them regardless of whether you define rules in a section of firewall resource or separate firewall rule resources. Or I didn't understand your setup. Maybe you could include your DO-specific code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question!

The solution is to use Terraform's `dynamic` block resource:

```
resource "digitalocean_firewall" "firewall" {
  name = "${var.project_name}-${var.environment}-firewall"

  inbound_rule {
    protocol         = "tcp"
    port_range       = "22"
    source_addresses = ["x.x.x.x/32"]
  }

  dynamic "inbound_rule" {
    for_each = module.ec2_node
    content {
      protocol         = "tcp"
      port_range       = "1-65535"
      source_addresses = [inbound_rule.value.public_ip]
    }
  }

  dynamic "inbound_rule" {
    for_each = module.ec2_node
    content {
      protocol         = "udp"
      port_range       = "1-65535"
      source_addresses = [inbound_rule.value.public_ip]
    }
  }
}
```